# Where does Steam store the gyro calibration settings?

Tags: steam, controllers, steam-in-home-streaming, steam-input

A bit of background:
I have an issue with my DS4 controller connected either wired or wireless. I use the controller's gyro mapped to act as a mouse to make it easier to aim in some games. When I use it locally on my laptop, it works fine but when I stream games from my PC to my laptop via in-home streaming, it goes haywire. It feels like the gyro is contradicting itself leading to jittering, erratic movements when used.

I used my DS4 once on my PC before and calibrated the gyro on there. I have a Switch Pro Controller that also has gyro but I never "calibrated" it on the PC and when I use that controller for in-home streaming, the jittering doesn't happen on gyro use.

So my totally baseless assumption is that, the reason gyro is acting up on my DS4 is because the calibration from the PC is contradicting the calibration from my laptop. So I want to find the gyro calibration settings on my PC and delete it or somehow reset it to the initial value.